# Acumatica - get the last displayed record

Tags: acumatica

Is there an eloquent way, more or less, to get the last displayed record in a grid in Acumatica? Let's say even if they do all the sorting and rearranging, is there a way for example when pressing a button on a grid to get the last record? Basically, I would like to copy that record as a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a PXAction for your button.
Inside the PXAction iterate in your data view until the last record.
For example, if the name of your Data view Bound to your grid is YzLines, and object type in the grid line (DAC) is Yz, then it can be:

```
Yz lastLine;
foreach (Yz line in YzLines.Select()) 
   lastLine = line;
```

To get to the last record you can also use .Last() or .LastOrDefault().

If you need the last record according to client sorting, you should implement a data view delegate, it looks like this:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable yzLines()
{
    PXSelectBase<Yz> cmd =
        new PXSelectJoinGroupBy<Yz, ...>(this);

    int startRow = PXView.StartRow; //Get starting row of the current page
    int totalRows = 0;

    foreach (PXResult<Yz> res in
                            cmd.View.Select(null, null,
                            PXView.Searches,
                            ARDocumentList.View.GetExternalSorts(),//Get sorting fields
                            ARDocumentList.View.GetExternalDescendings(),//Get sorting direction
                            ARDocumentList.View.GetExternalFilters(),//Get filters
                            ref startRow,
                            PXView.MaximumRows, //Get count of records in the page
                            ref totalRows))
    {
        //processing of records
    }

    PXView.StartRow = 0;//Reset starting row
}
```

Comment: Would that get the last record displayed in the grid? I thought OP wanted last record taking into account sort and paging. Something like view delegates: Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters,        
       PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, 
       PXView.Filters, ref startrow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalrow)

Comment: Otherwise yeah, YzLines.Select().LastOrDefault() will do it.

Comment: Ilya, the example you posted would not work. It does not take into account if they sort columns or move them around.

@HB_ACUMATICA is there an example of PXView somewhere? Would you happen to have it for this scenario?

Comment: Stan, if you need to take into account client sorting, you should write a data view delegate (I've posted code sample into the original answer). See T200 course and help.acumatica.com for details on data view delegates.

Comment: Thanks, Ilya. I will try this later today. The following also helps, if you want to avoid copying original BQL: http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/06/using-pxview-in-dataview-delegate.html